# Distinguish between Node's native functions and anonymous functions

Tags: types, node.js, anonymous-function, mongoose

I'm looking for a way to traverse through an object and perform an action if I have an anonymous function and not perform the action if I have a native function.

This is best explained with an example:

```
User = {
   first : String,
   last : String,
   email : function(email) {
     // ....
   }
}

User.forEach(function(prop) {
   if(! native ) {
      // Do something
   }
});
```

Gut reaction is of course not, but console.log will output `[Function: String]` for the String native function, and `[Function]` for anonymous functions.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toString()` to look at the text of the function then look for functions without names:

`/^function\s*?\(/.test(prop.toString())`